# Prove special case of two class softmax is equivalent to logistic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A textbook I'm reading asks to prove that the special case of a two value softmax is equivalent to a sigmoid/logistic function.  It defines the softmax as:
$$
\frac{e^{H_t(a)}}{\sum_{b=1}^ke^{H_t(b)}}
$$

I made the first logical leap to:

$$
\frac{e^x}{e^x + e^y}
$$

Wolfram Alpha tells me that this is equivalent to the logistic function but fails to give a step by step proof how.  I've played around with it for awhile now but I'm not particularly talented at math "puzzles" so I don't get very far.  How do I get from where I'm at to a sigmoid?

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $e^x$